# React HOC wrapping with Clojurescript and Reagent

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

I'm trying re-use the components from `react-google-maps` and implement the simple map example from the doc: https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/basics/simple-map

However, I'm a blocked by the `withGoogleMap` Higher-Order Component (HOC) that wraps the `GoogleMap` component. I have tried to adapt the classes with Reagent and use them as follow:

```
(def GoogleMap (adapt-react-class js/ReactGoogleMaps.GoogleMap))
(def withGoogleMap (adapt-react-class js/ReactGoogleMaps.withGoogleMap))

(defn Map [props]
  [withGoogleMap
   [GoogleMap props]])
```

in lieu of the following Javascript:

```
const Map = withGoogleMap(props => (
  <GoogleMap
     {... props}
  >
  </GoogleMap>
));
```

Without success. (I get the following error `withGoogleMap(...): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`withGoogleMap` HOC is a function](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/blob/master/lib/withGoogleMap.js) that should be called with the wrapped component. To implement the [simple map example](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/basics/simple-map), you also need to provide props to the `GoogleMap` component to be wrapped. This can be achieved by adapting the component to reagent with `adapt-react-class`, implementing the CLJS component, and "converting back" with `reactify-component` before calling the HOC.

```
(ns simple-map.views
  (:require [reagent.core :refer [adapt-react-class 
                                  create-element 
                                  reactify-component]]
            react-google-maps))

(defn my-google-map []
  (let [google-map (adapt-react-class react-google-maps/GoogleMap)]
    [google-map {:defaultZoom   18
                 :defaultCenter {:lat 61.4481532
                                 :lng 23.8608644}}]))

(defn MyMap [props]
  (let [m (-> my-google-map
              reactify-component
              react-google-maps/withGoogleMap
              adapt-react-class)]
    [m props]))

(defn main-panel []
  (let [container-element (create-element "div" #js{:style (clj->js {:height "768px" :width "1024px"})})
        map-element       (create-element "div" #js{:style (clj->js {:height "768px" :width "1024px"})})]
    (fn []
      [:div
       [MyMap {:containerElement container-element
               :mapElement       map-element}]])))
```

Note that I am using [the experimental :npm-deps support](https://cljs.github.io/api/compiler-options/npm-deps) to require `react-google-maps`.

Comment: Thanks! This was probably the longest React interop I wrote! I noticed you can simplify the `create-element` in `(create-element "div" (clj->js {:style {:height "768px" :width "1024px"}}))`

Comment: @sebastie no problem! (I noticed you already answered the question I had about your comment)